# mysql database unique id gets repeated after been deleted a day after

Tags: mysql

This is actually a question, i noticed a pattern in my mysql database on my hosting server

so i have a table "users",

**users has a unique id "userid"  which is generates id automatically as per every new record.**

So i noticed what seems to be an abnormal thing

i delete a record from the row with user id "4"

**a day after if a record comes into database table the userid "4" is regenerated.**

This i think is not normal

Has anyone experienced this

my create statement of table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `User_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `Username` text NOT NULL,
  `Password` text NOT NULL,
  `Access` text NOT NULL,
  `Email` text NOT NULL,
  `business` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `User_id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I was hoping once an id is deleted, it is never repeated

Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;`

Comment: How do you generate id´s??

Comment: auto increment @nacho

Comment: what you say isn't possible.. `AUTO_INCREMENT` should never repeat numbers, unless somebody/something willingly had reset/changed the `AUTO_INCREMENT` for that table with a `ALTER `command

Comment: ah i see @RaymondNijland

Comment: @EugenRieck iv update my question

Comment: wat do u advice i do stop this issue please @RaymondNijland

Comment: Don´t execute the alter table and don´t modify the autoincrement value

Comment: ok @nacho at the moment the table has alot of data what do i do, is there a way i can fix my table to not do the alter thingy

Comment: But a AUTO_INCREMENT also does not stop somebody from inserting a record userid "4" directly in the database after deleting userid "4"  to also make one thing clear

Comment: yea i get that, i just want to make sure that wen a form submits "4" is nt repeated in the db @RaymondNijland

Comment: So make it a unique key

Comment: you mean my userid field, thanks @nacho

Comment: i thought making a field a primary key makes it unique @nacho

Comment: my userid field is unique just checked it

Comment: Yes, but once you delete a user_id, you can insert the same user_id again.

Comment: ooo so wat am experiencing is normal then, i thought it was odd

Comment: there isn't a key/index option in MySQL which prevents old deleted generated id's from inserting again..  One thing you can do is make a table with old id's and check it with a trigger and stop the insert, update from happing if a inserted/updated id matches a old delete id

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the meaning of `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`:

- It will **never autogenerate** an ID that has already been taken **any time in the known past**.
- It will **always allow manual insertion**  of an ID that is not in use **currently**

So: If you delete an ID and manually reinsert it, the Database will not stop you, but if you let the database create an ID it will never repeat.

**EDIT**

There is good reason to allow manual insertion of a once-deleted ID: Without it, a partial restoreof a table would be if not impossible then much more complicated.

Comment: *"If you delete an ID and manually reinsert it, the Database will not stop you, but if you let the database create an ID it will never repeat."* Very true  only valid workaround which you can do is make a table with old id's and check it with a trigger and stop the insert, update from happing if a inserted/updated id matches a old deleted id

Comment: but that is what happns to my table once i delete a record from my db with say id "4" and the next day a user submits a form that id gets regenerated, its weird to me

Comment: and this is the first hosting server its happnd to me, so its very weird

Comment: This is the way it works, and with good reason (see my edit) - if you create new users you simply should not allow to set a user id, but let the database handle it.